# Error: Could not connect to www.browserstack.com! Response Code : [object Object]

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, local, browserstack

I am trying to run the BrowserStackLocal binary file to enable the Local Testing, however, I am getting the below error-

```
Error: Could not connect to www.browserstack.com! Response Code : [object Object]
```

I am able to run this binary file on my personal machine and not able to run the same file from my company computer.

```java
./BrowserStackLocal --key my_bs_key
```

Comment: firewall issues, probably behind a corporate network

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to your firewall blocking `browserstack.com` or not allowing to make socket connections to remote hosts with urls `*.browserstack.com`. It could also be that you behind a proxy. If in case of proxy you can pass the appropriate proxy params documented [here](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing/binary-params)